# Problem with two abstract noun usages describe a perfume

Tags: nouns

For every Casanova, here is an eau de parfum inviting intense pleasure, an amber fern mixing fine **wooded tunes** and **touches** of lemony freshness, sublimed by the elegance of lavender. Warmed with heady spices and colored by sweet fruits.

amber fern is kind of plants/spices used in this perfume. why it has **wooded tunes**?

Why lemony freshness has **touches**.

I know the meaning is quite abstract here, I will appreciate similar usage/examples to demonstrate the meaning. Thanks.

Source: http://www.histoiresdeparfums.com/us/histoiresdeparfums/characters-masculine.php

Comment: I don't actually see a question here.  What, specifically, is your problem?

Comment: sorry, doesn't finish the question here. Edited already.

Comment: I'm guessing **tunes** is an affected version of **(over)tones**, and **wooded** is the same for **woody** (aromatic cedarwood, pinewood, etc.). But **touch** (as in [a touch of xxx](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+touch+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)) is bog-standard metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

To say A has "a touch of B" means "just a little bit". Like if you say, "This drink is mint-flavored", that would mean that it tastes like mint, period. The overall taste is mint. But if you say, "This drink has a touch of mint flavor", that means it is mostly some other flavor, but there is a little bit of mint in it.

Making "touches" plural just increases it slightly. So "This drink has touches of mint flavor" is a little more minty than "... has a touch". In some contexts it may mean several different kinds. Like if you say, "This book has touches of *Lord of the Rings*", you probably mean that it has several elements that might remind someone of *Lord of the Rings*. But it's pretty vague and abstract.

So "... touches of lemony freshness" would mean that it does not smell like lemons, but it has some hint of lemon smell, mixed in with other smells.

"Wooded tunes" doesn't make a lot of literal sense. Maybe they're trying to say that it brings to mind the sound of music played on wooden instruments, or on woodwind instruments?

This is very poetic language, so it's not clear how literally to take any of it.

Comment: +1 because although I can't really disagree with @jwpat7's "advertising copy", I think in the end it's more appropriate here to call it "very poetic language".

Answer (score 1):

When describing sensory experiences, writers sometimes conflate the inputs of different senses. The resulting style could be described as *synaesthetic*, after the condition [synaesthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaesthesia), in which affected individuals experience a blurring of what for most people are distinct senses. This is especially common when discussing music - e.g. among certain enlightened circles one often encounters talk of *tone colours*, sounds having a *texture*, or occasionally of notes having a *fruity* sound.

However, as others have mentioned, this is quite separate from the well-established idiom *'a touch of'*, which simply means a little of something, although I suspect that it evolved from a similar origin, perhaps as an extension of *'a pinch of'* and other similar phrases.

Answer (score 0):

That text is [advertising copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advertising_copy).  Wikipedia says advertising copy is writing that's promotional [rather than meaningful] and has the purpose of persuading the reader to buy a product.

The words "amber fern" perhaps make one think of yellow sunny areas; the only real reference I've found shows a [bit of fern in amber](http://www.flickr.com/photos/eckiblue/135487577/), while most references for the term are proper names or pseudonyms, or fictional, from Star Wars planet [Mandalore](http://www.cuswe.org/newdescr.asp?search=60432).

Rather than *tunes* being "an affected version of (over)tones" as FumbleFingers suggested, I suspect the writer merely confused the words *tunes* and *tones*, intending the latter.

*Touch* as used here means a hint, a small amount. (See [noun sense #5](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/touch).)

"Warmed with heady spices and colored by sweet fruits" is not intended to refer to "general spices we mean when cooking" but instead to spice scents as in [incense](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incense) or [potpourri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potpourri).  The main purpose is to make the reader think of fine smells and tastes so that he or she will feel good, and likely to part with money more readily, and thus more likely to buy the product.

Comment: Much as we might like to look down on their efforts, I think we should allow that people paid to write "advertising copy" for perfumes costing hundreds of dollars an ounce are almost certainly at least *literate*. I note that OP's selected passage actually starts with *"Venice, the riparian city of love"*. People who know the word *"riparian"* aren't likely to accidentally conflate *tunes* and *tones*. I stand by my contention that it was deliberate "affectation" (and possibly even field-tested to make sure the punters were suitably affected by it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - What nonsense! Venice is not riparian, it is estuarian.  As noted in wikipedia, the [Venetian lagoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venetian_Lagoon) is "an enclosed, shallow embayment of saltwater, a lagoon."

Comment: Aw, c'mon! These people are ad-men, not geographers! I didn't know it was saltwater either, and to be honest it doesn't make me think *riparian* can't be used. Rivers, canals, freshwater, saltwater - all seems much of a muchness to me. It's just boats and watersides.

Comment: The language all seems rather excessive to me. But I suppose if I was assigned to write advertising copy for a perfume, I'd probably come up with something like, "It smells nice, kinda like flowers or lemons or fruit or something." Well, hmm, that's pretty much what they said, they were just a lot more flowery about it. Does this kind of prose really sell? I wonder if they just said, "Lavender and lemon scent" or whatever, if that would sell just as well. I realize balding old geeks like me are not their target audience.

Comment: thefreedictionary.com defines riparian as relating to the "banks of a natural course of water". It doesn't say it has to be a river. The "natural course" implies to me that it excludes canals, but I don't know if that's what's meant.

Comment: @Jay - That [source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/riparian) quotes four dictionaries; two definitions are as you say, and two  say _river_.  Why? Because *[riparian](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=riparian)* 'comes from L. _riparius_ "of a river bank," ... "later used in ref. to the stream flowing between the banks, from _ripa_ "(steep) bank of a river, shore".'  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riparian) notes that "Riparian zones may be natural or engineered..." and shows a canal with no  riparian margin. Venice does not have riparian zones along its canals.