# The specific meaning of 'spices' when describe a kind of perfume

Tags: nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with two abstract noun usages describe a perfume](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57199/problem-with-two-abstract-noun-usages-describe-a-perfume)

For every Casanova, here is an eau de parfum inviting intense pleasure... Warmed with heady **spices** and colored by sweet fruits.

Under this context, I thought the **spices** are not the general spices we mean when cooking because the author has already named some specific components used in this perfume. So what's the meaning of this **spices**?

source: http://www.histoiresdeparfums.com/us/histoiresdeparfums/characters-masculine.php

Comment: Don't copy your question. Edit the other one to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

English has virtually no words that denote scent exclusively, especially pleasant scents. There, everything is metaphor.

In the parlance of certain technical groups, *spices* may indeed have a very specific reference -- even going so far in some cases as naming the chemical congeners -- but wine tech talk, cheese tech talk, chef tech talk, perfume tech talk -- and many many other ingroup technical dialects where a ***Spice*** metaphor is used descriptively -- will vary **enormously** on the details of what is meant by it.

In other words, talk to a perfumer and get examples. That's the only way you'll ever find out. We can only offer speculation here, unless someone here is a perfumer (which is possible). If so, defer to their opinion.

This is all assuming, of course, that whoever wrote the sentence knew what they were talking about, and how to talk about it meaningfully. This may well not be true, especially in advertising copy.